# Premiere export colors

Tags: premiere, color-correction, color-grading

I know I am not the first, but I also have terrible problems with making the export with (latest) Premier Pro in an iMac. I looked through a lot of forums and I cannot find a solution anywhere…
As you can see on the picture, not just that the colors are shifted but also the image / skin colors completely fall apart when I export it…

The higher image is a thumbnail saved from Premiere, lower one is played on VLC (similar to the look on YouTube and other players).
I tried everything I could think of and I am not able to get any better result at all.
I have tried exporting with Premiere and Media encoder.
Using CUDA and software encoding.
Using different codes bitrates for export HD h.264 on 10,35,50mbps, h.265, QuickTime Prores 422HQ, mpeg, jpg export, and it is all more or less the same… every time the skin fell apart.
I tried turning on and off export form previews, render at maximum depth, maximum render quality…
I tried exporting with the LUT from Adobe and it changes color completely in to something else, but the skin still falls apart.

The strangest I think is the difference between save snapshot from the timeline and the frame from jpg export. Does anybody have any idea what to do?
Last resort would be to go frame by frame saving snapshots from program monitor and encoding with something else, but there must be a better way?

Any suggestions??

Thank you.

[image: the problem]

Comment: The underlying problem seems that the P3 colour space monitor that iMacs use is unsuitable for a Rec.709 compliant workflow. This video explains how color spaces work in Premiere: https://mixinglight.com/color-grading-tutorials/demystifying-premiere-pros-color-management-and-finishing-pipeline/ Apparently, there is a workaround. But since I don't have Apple hardware I can't share any experience. Also the article and video where they explain the workaround requires a membership, so I didn't watch the 2nd part: https://mixinglight.com/color-grading-tutorials/premiere-pro-hdr-apple-p3-displays/

Comment: @Matt it’s not the P3 color space as much as apples botched interpretation of rec.709.  But apple’s “display P3” is not actual P3, either. The point is, even if he changed his monitor to rec.709, he’d still get a color shift.

Comment: Can I just say that whatever they're doing with that angle grinder looks hella dangerous. Where's the guard? And they've got a ring on.